# Cuantos hombres y mujeres son beneficiadas según el estrato y edad en Python

Tags: python-3.x

las beneficiadas serán las mujeres que tengan 25 años o menos  y quienes siendo hombres no superen los 30 años, solo aplica para estratos 1 y 3

```
    1. Cuantos hombres  son beneficiados
    2. Cuantas mujeres  son beneficiadas
    3. Mostrar el promedio de edad de hombres beneficiados
    4. Mostrar el promedio de edad de mujeres beneficiadas
```

nota: mediante un mensaje decir si no es beneficiado, se usar clases

no logro resolver cuantos son beneficiados tanto en hombres como mujeres, tengo ya esta parte hecha

```
año_actual=int(input("ingrese año actual"))
estrato=int(input("¿cual es tu estrato? 1 o 2"))
sexo=input("¿cual es tu sexo? hombre o mujer")

edad_suma_promedio=[]

class personas():
        
    def leer_edades():
        while True:
            año_nacimiento= int(input("año de nacimiento"))
            edad=año_actual-año_nacimiento
           
            if edad<=30 and sexo== "hombre" and estrato==1 or estrato==3:
                edad_suma_promedio.append(edad) 
                print("eres beneficado")
                
            elif edad<=25 and sexo=="mujer" and estrato==1 or estrato==3:
                edad_suma_promedio.append(edad) 
                print("eres beneficiada")
            else:
                print("no eres beneficiario")
                
            otra=input("¿deseo otro calculo? s/n")
            if otra=="n" or otra=="N":
                break

    def promedio():
        suma_edades=0
        for e in edad_suma_promedio:
            suma_edades +=e
        p=suma_edades / len(edad_suma_promedio)
        return p

    leer_edades()
    print("el promedio de edad es: {}".format(promedio()))
```

Comment: Por que no trabajas con una lista para los hombres y otra lista para las mujeres? Esa sería la solución.

Comment: a que te refieres con estratos? no se si es obligacion meter los datos a manos, pero si vienen en archivo mejor usar pandas, luego de eso se resuelve con 4 lineas. Pero si quieres desarrollar el codigo por ti mismo entonces tendras que almacenar cada uno de los datos en una lista y de forma posterior al ingreso, recorrerlos y evaluar las condiciones para cada registro para modificar tus contados, concluyendo en el resultado.